# How can I prevent simultaneous data fetching by independent components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a large application, where I use redux to store my fetched data. Each component that needs data ensures it will get what it needs by running request and waits for the data to appear in
`useSelector(state => state.dataReducer.data)`.

In most simple use it is ok, but when two components on the same page require same data, they both run fetching

My solution is (code simplified, I tried many ways of accessing store)

```
if(store.getState().requests.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
   return false
}

store.dispatch(setRequest(url));

get(url).finally(() => {
   store.dispatch(unsetRequest(dataKey));});
})
```

Unfortunately, async store update do not perform its operations when I need them to be performed, and when 2 simultaneous requests run, state has not been updated yet.

For testing purposes, I run the other request with timeout of 200ms and it is OK, but in normal application context, it's not possible.
How to prevent this?

Comment: ***Don't*** re-invent the wheel, integrate [Redux-Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) (*it's almost too trivial if you are already using Redux-Toolkit*) and the API slice/endpoints you declares will basically handle this endpoint "de-duplication" automagically.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem.
There will be a lot of ways to do it but the general idea should be that your store should be aware that a similar API call is already in-flight. You can save lifecycle states such as `loading | loaded | null` and so on for every `URL + method + (data/queryParams)` combo. Check this state before making any API call.

The above you might be able to do using some hashmap. But a custom implementation for such a general problem is not required.
`redux-saga`, `redux-thunk` might be of help. `react-query` should also be useful

Answer (score 0):

These 3 libraries solve your problem:

- [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)
- [RTKQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)
- [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/overview)

Pick the one that aligns the best for your project.